# Translate Sitecore Form Date Min and Max date Validation message in Spanish

Tags: sitecore-forms, fieldtype

I am using sitecore form date control and specififed min and max date.
when trying to enter date more than max value getting below validation message  :
"Please enter a value less than or equal to 2023-09-08."

How to translate this error message in other language such as spanish and korea.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced similar issue with Sitecore Forms email field validation message in German language.

I have blogged my solution in below link :

https://letsmakesitecoresimplecom.wordpress.com/2023/08/18/extended-translation-for-sitecore-form/

Take a look at this and try it if matches your issue.

Note - There is some limitation in my solution, which I have explained in detail in same blog post.

Hope it helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

All the form field validators are defined in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations/` part of the tree, e.g.

```
/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations/Date Validator
```

[image]

Add new language version to chosen validator and type the correct `Message` value for given language. Remember to publish the item.

[image]

I don't see a message like you mentioned in your question in any of out of the box validators or Forms Extensions module validators. I assume that's a custom validator - find correct item under `Validations` node.

Comment: Not using any custom field or Validation.
Using OOTB Date control and added StartDate and EndDate. after that if entring value less or more by typing then getting this message which I need to translate.

Comment: Those messages comes from jquey validation plugin. You can read SO discussion how to localize those messages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630386/translate-custom-jquery-validation-messages